# KubeSchedulerConfiguration is not available to the componentconfig API

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I am trying to disable preemption on a `Kubernetes 1.11.0` cluster.

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#how-to-disable-preemption) this can be done by setting

`disablePreemption: true`

in the `KubeSchedulerConfiguration` via the `componentconfig/v1alpha1` API.

The error that I am getting when I try this is `no matches for kind "KubeSchedulerConfiguration" in version "componentconfig/v1alpha1"`.

I tried to explicitly turn on the `componentconfig/v1alpha1` API, but it doesn't show up in `kubectl api-versions`.

Is there something that I am missing to make the component config API recognize the `KubeSchedulerConfiguration` object?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share your configuration file?

Comment: I think the alpha versions will not be enabled by default [K8S-API Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/). Can you please post the API runtime-config attribute that you set in API server ? .